# Chrome Develop tool don't show class , but python beautifulsoup find function shows class

Tags: python, html

I am making to get the stock price using beautilfulsoup.

But when I use chrome dev tool. there is no class blind.

But when I use beautifulsoup find function, there is class blind.

So, I don't know why this is diffrent. Anybody know why this is diffrent, please let me know!

[Beautifulsoup find result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLSic.png)
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlwYX.png)

[Chrome dev tool don't display class blind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go0lD.png)

Comment: The DOM might have been changed with JavaScript in Chrome.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900